# Android Terminal Emulator commands

Tags: android

I'm a root user but I can't execute certain commands. What Linux commands can be executed in Android Terminal Emulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full list of commands you can execute.

```
monkey        showlease       dosfsck       dhcpcd
am            gzip            check_prereq  dvz
ime           logcat          applypatch    flash_image
input         servicemanager  debuggerd     getevent
pm            qemud           linker        getprop
svc           radiooptions    logwrapper    hd
debug_tool    vold            ping          id
gdbserver     dumpstate       recovery      insmod
htclogkernel  toolbox         schedtest     installd
iftop         sh              ifconfig
```

```
add-property-tag  check-lost+found  cpueater   latencytop
nc                netperf           netserver  scp
showslab          ssh               strace     su
dexdump           librank           procrank   procmem
backup            crasher           pppd       showmap
daemonize         sqlite3           timeinfo
```